# socket.io give me blocked by CORS policy even if the call came from the same server

Tags: ubuntu, socket.io

I am getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://example.com:3003/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NFm_Nq4'
> from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

my server.js

```
var app = require('express')(); 
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var debug = require('debug')('Gentack:Chat');
var request = require('request');
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
var socket_url = process.env.APP_URL;

var port = process.env.PORT || '3003';

if(SSL_KEY && SSL_CERTIFICATE) {

    var fs = require('fs');

    var https = require('https');
    
    var server = https.createServer({     
                    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"),
                    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem") 
                 },app);

     
    server.listen(port);

} else {

    var server = require('http').Server(app);

    server.listen(port);

}
```

I checked the port 3003 and it is open